# How to use a parent record's value in rails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, parent-child

I have a rails 3.2 application in which I have a simple parent/child relationship in which I need to use values from the parent to validate attributes in the child.  The models look like this:

```
class RubricItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :max_score, :min_score, :name, :order
  has_many :rubric_ranges
end
```

and

```
class RubricRange < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :helper, :range_max, :range_min, :rubric_item_id
  validates_presence_of :helper, :range_max, :range_min
  validates :range_max, :range_min, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}
  validates :range_max, :numericality => { :greater_than => :range_min }
  belongs_to :rubric_item
end
```

I want to be able to validate two different things.  First, for a rubric_range, I want to validate that its range_min value is >= to its parents rubic.min_score and that range_max <= to its parent rubric.max_score.

Secondly, I want to validate that other rubric_ranges have unique min/max values.  In other words, there cannot be two rubric_ranges defined for the same value, so if one cover 0-2, another must not include 0, 1 or 2 in its range.  Example: the first range is 0-2, if one defines a 2-4 range I want to raise a validation error within the scope of the parent.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parent almost the usual way you use parent:

```
class RubricRange < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validate :has_proper_range
  ...
  def has_proper_range
    error.add(:range_min, ' cannot be smaller than RubricItem minimum score') if range_min < rubric_item.min_score
    error.add(:range_max, ' cannot be greater than RubricItem maximum score') if range_max > rubric_item.max_score
  end
```

The only problem is if you want to create RubricRange item together with RubricItem using nested_attributes, as build method on association does not set the reverse relationship for new records.

Second validation can be done by simply noticing, that it is to fail if there is any other range with min or max within given range. Hence:

```
validate :do_not_overlap_with_other_ranges
...
def do_not_overlap_with_other_ranges
  overlapping_ranges = self.class.where('(range_min >= :min AND range_min <= :max) OR (range_max >= :min AND range_max <= :max)', {:min => range_min, :max => range_max})
  overlapping_ranges = overlapping_ranges.where.not(:id => id) unless new_record?
  errors.add(:base, 'Range overlapping with another range') if overlapping_ranges.exists?
end
```

(Please feel free to comment on the query above as I think there should be nicer way to write this).

Comment: This worked great with just a few edits (I already submitted them).  Here is the updated full (and working!) query:     overlapping_ranges = self.class.where('( id = :id AND (range_min >= :min AND range_min <= :max) OR (range_max >= :min AND range_max <= :max))', {:id => rubric_item_id, :min => range_min, :max => range_max})

Comment: Actually I had to update the query to allow updates to pass validation by excluding the current record's min/max:

    overlapping_ranges = self.class.where('( id <> :myid AND rubric_item_id == :riid AND ( (range_min >= :min AND range_min <= :max) OR (range_max >= :min AND range_max <= :max) ) )', {:myid => id, :riid => rubric_item_id, :min => range_min, :max => range_max})